# Wake word detection in porcupine

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to implement porcupine wakeword in python and have followed the instructions from [here](https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine/tree/master/binding/python)

I have the following code:

```
import pvporcupine

### Porcupine wakeword
handle = pvporcupine.create(keywords=['computer', 'jarvis'])

def get_next_audio_frame():
    pass

while True:
    keyword_index = handle.process(get_next_audio_frame())
    if keyword_index >= 0:
        # Insert detection event callback here
        print('Yes sir?')
        pass
```

but I receive the following error:

```
❯ python3 porcupine.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File "porcupine.py", line 10, in <module>
    keyword_index = handle.process(get_next_audio_frame())   File "/home/rupstar/Computer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pvporcupine/porcupine.py", line 129, in process
    if len(pcm) != self.frame_length: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: You literally defined `get_next_audio_frame` to just `pass`, meaning `None` is returned. So why do you expect `handle.process(None)` to work? According to the [source code](https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine/blob/7a13cde4b9e7a02c39ad44f0dc6faea8c8933b75/binding/python/porcupine.py#L118), the `pcm` argument is supposed to be " A frame of audio samples.", not `None`. The reason that example has `pass` in `get_next_audio_frame` is just because it's an example. You're meant to actually do something instead of just `pass`.

Comment: Thanks @RandomDavis... I'm very new to this, so your comment is very useful in making me learn. So essentially I have to tell it to listen for sound for a period and then repeat until it hears the wakeword? And then I have to tell my voice assistant to listen to the commands... I think I can integrate the second bit easily, but I'll struggle with the first bit... at least I have direction now. Thanks again!

Comment: That's not what I'm saying at all. I don't know what `pvporcupine` does exactly or how it works. All I'm saying that `get_next_audio_frame` has to return audio, meaning you have to capture it from somewhere. There could be existing examples online of how to combine `pvporcupine` with some other library that captures audio.

Comment: @RandomDavis thanks for the direction, it was just what I needed! I have now captured the audio and implemented it successfully into my voice assistant, so no pvporcupine (which is a wakeword detector) now hears me when I say "Jarvis" or "Computer", and then I can give it commands to do things on my Windows 10 computer; e.g. open applications, return wikipedia entries, tell me the time, the date, the weather based on location, a joke, etc., etc.,... all from the ubuntu command line running on WSL2!

Comment: Cool, glad that helped. You can post your solution as an answer and accept it if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be perfect (it isn't), but it shows how I've created a personal voice assistant in python on WSL2 running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Windows 10 machine. The voice assistant responds to a wakeword (Jarvis or Computer) and then executes commands.
Relevant to this post is how porcupine is invoked:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#Porcupine wakeword includes
import struct
import pyaudio
import pvporcupine

porcupine = None
pa = None
audio_stream = None

try:
    porcupine = pvporcupine.create(keywords=["computer", "jarvis"])

    pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    audio_stream = pa.open(
                    rate=porcupine.sample_rate,
                    channels=1,
                    format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=porcupine.frame_length)

    while True:
        pcm = audio_stream.read(porcupine.frame_length)
        pcm = struct.unpack_from("h" * porcupine.frame_length, pcm)

        keyword_index = porcupine.process(pcm)

        if keyword_index >= 0:
            print("Hotword Detected")
            speak("Computer online")
```

Comment: Consider posting only the code that is relevant to OP's question, and explain that part. You can still link the rest.